# SSRS 2016 user needs Publisher role to display charts of type "comparison time chart"

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016 Enterprise with SSRS in Native Mode. 
I am using the Mobile Report Publisher to generate mobile Reports. My data source is a SSAS Cube. Today I ran in some issues regarding permissions. The user who executes the report seems to need the "Publisher" role within the datasource. That doesn't make sense to me, because the user mustn't publish reports but only execute them. When I opt the permission "Publisher" out, I can't retrieve report information from the diagramm type "comparision time chart". Gauges do work actually. 
If i grant the user the "Publisher" role the diagram gets displayed. In my opinion the role "Browser" should be just fine for that requirement.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you doing row level security on your cube?

Comment: Yes I do. There are defined roles within the cube and the users can only see the data they are allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by myself. I compared the permissions of the roles "Browser" and "Publisher". Those roles are completely different. The "Publisher" role has the permission "Manage data sources". When you connect to the SSRS within SSMS you can edit the roles. I granted the "Browser" role that permission and it worked. But the "Browser" role should not be able to edit data sources, so I only granted the role the permission to "view data sources" and it worked also.